# Extract RDF from LinkedIn profiles if it is using RDF

Tags: xml, rdf, rdfs

Does LinkedIn using RDF for profiles and if yes, how it can be extracted?

Normal extractors respond empty pages which means there is no RDF on that page.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn is generally very protective of it's page data. They may expose RDF (schema.org) to major search engines to help with SEO but even that is difficult to verify unless you can convince their stack that your request is coming from a crawler they trust.

Depending on what you're trying to do, perhaps you can use their [API](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api)?